# Android - Google Maps Touch and Drag Marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

How would I go through moving a marker on a Map Activity without having to long click and hold that marker until it receives focus?

I just want to touch and drag, but it takes around 1-2 secs before it receives focus and fires drag event.

here's my code:

```
   mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .draggable(true));

            markers.add(marker);

            updateUI();
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

            updateUI();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
            updateUI();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            updateUI();
        }
    });
```

Comment: By checking this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#make_a_marker_draggable) about Marker to be draggable and this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#marker_drag_events) about Marker drag events, it seems that you have no any problem with the coding. So I think the 1-2 secs that you say is only natural for the draggable marker. You can confirm it by checking the video inside of this [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/01/google-maps-android-api-v2-example_7.html).