# How to move marker on tap instead of long press

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, drag

**What I want ?**

When user taps on marker its image should change and user should be able to move the marker and I should be able to get the latitude and longitude . Below is a video of requirement .

**What I have tried so far ?**

I tried to implement default marker drag listener but it only works with long press .

I looked on similar questions on stack overflow but no luck .

Tried with ground overlay but not had much luck .

[image]

So how can I achieve this behaviour , Any hint is appreciated . There is already an app out there which does it so this should be possible .

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) you are required to use:

```
GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener
public static interface GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener
```

Which Defines signatures for methods that are called when a marker is clicked or tapped.

With public method:

```
abstract boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
```

Called when a marker has been clicked or tapped.

**INSTEAD OF**

```
GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener
public static interface GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener
```

with Public method:

public abstract void [onMapLongClick](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener#onMapLongClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) ([LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) point)
Called when the user makes a long-press gesture on the map, but only if none of the overlays of the map handled the gesture. Implementations of this method are always invoked on the Android UI thread.

Comment: googlemap.clear();
        googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true));

Comment: That will move marker only on long press . I want to move marker by tap and drag

Comment: If so question is dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561108/android-google-maps-touch-and-drag-marker

Comment: Its not exact duplicate